# How to iterate over a dictionary and a list simultaneously?

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

I have to "encrypt" a textfile. I have to substitute the text characters with dictionary values. The keys are alphabet letters. For example if the text is "Hello" and in my dictionary "h":"a", "e":"d" I want to replace "Hello" with "adllo". How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried ? A simple approach would be to read each character, look it up in a dictionary and append the replacement value in a new list.

Comment: Or you could do all this on the fly and just join the newly created string with the replacements coming from the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans)--which allows creation of a translation table
- [translate](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate)--applies translation table from maketrans to a string

**Code**

```
def encrypt(infile, outfile, translation):
    '''
        Encrypts by applying translation map to characters in file infile.
    '''
    # Create translation table
    table = ''.maketrans(translation)
    
    # Apply table to all characters in input file
    # and write to new output file
    with open(infile, "r") as fin, open(outfile, "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.translate(table))
```

**Test**

```
# Dictionary containing map of letters to their new values
d = {"H":"a", "e":"d", "l": "k", "o":"n"}

# Encryp filel 'input.txt'
encrypt('input.txt', "output.txt", d)

# Show Result
print(open("output.txt").read())
```

Input file 'input.txt:

```
Hello
World
```

Output file 'output.txt' (letters specified in dictionary d are replaced)

```
adkkn
Wnrkd
```